# Which of the Peter Pan adaptations share canon with the 1953 animated film?

Tags: canon, peter-pan

There have been a large number of Peter Pan adaptations over the years, but I am specifically interested in the films and TV series spawned from or related to the original Disney movie and how they relate:

- [Original Film, Peter Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan_(1953_film))
- [Sequel Film, Return to Neverland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Never_Land)
- [Prequel Film *series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_Bell_(film_series))
- [Sequel TV Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jake_and_the_Never_Land_Pirates)
- [Sequel Live-Action Film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_(film))

(Are there any others?)

Are these stories all interconnected, or are there disconnects where only the setting or select character names are the same?

Obviously this is not a detailed planned out universe as we have seen in recent years such as with Marvel films, but I'm still curious as to what if anything does connect the various adaptations?

Comment: Well... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_based_on_Peter_Pan

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron well? Are they or aren't they interconnected?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I believe that was in reference to "*Are there any others?*" to which the answer is ***"Yes, shedloads"***

Comment: Although there have been many spin-offs and "retellings", my understanding is that the only specifically canon addition to the 1953 film is its direct sequel, *Return to Neverland*.

Comment: @Valorum so none of the works (besides those two) and properly linked? Because Hook seems internally consistent with the 1953 film, but I don't know about the animated sequel and if it would ruin any links be revealing 'forgotten' canon (from the perspective of Hook). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 7):

It's important to note the original novel was published in 1911 and [has been public domain for some time](https://www.gosh.org/about-us/peter-pan/copyright/). Only the stage play is still copyrighted.

The original Disney film only really ever has [Return to Neverland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Never_Land) as any sort of official canon.

The *Tinkerbell* movies never mention Peter Pan or Never Land for that matter. Indeed, they feature a talking Tinkerbell (something no main canon movie portrays). They have it so humans can only hear her "tinkering bell" sound when she speaks. The closest any of them ever come to the source material would be [The Pirate Fairy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirate_Fairy), which is ostensibly the story of how James Hook became Captain Hook and how they at least attempted to reach Never Land (they sail towards the "second star to the right" under the power of pixie dust but are stopped).

*Jake and the Never Land Pirates* was a Disney Junior show (they bolted counting coins for doing good deeds on so they could count it as educational). While the show is set in Never Land, Peter Pan does show up from time to time, and Captain Hook and Smee are recurring villains, there's no indication of how it fits into any canon beyond borrowing the elements of the film. They don't really deal with the deeper themes of the books or movies. It's just a kids' show.

*Hook* was a work by Steven Spielberg based off the original books as far as I can tell. Tinkerbell talks (and even expresses a romantic desire for grown-up Peter Pan). Wendy got old. James Hook missed his old nemesis. But it simply borrows from the original material as well. There's nothing to indicate a connection to the Disney film (which would have run afoul of copyright). The same goes for [Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_(2015_film)), which is a prequel to the book.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for. Thank you! I thought Hook was a part Disney production, which is why I made the original connnection.